# Мой JavaScript в Cordova

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova

Доброго времени суток. Создал пустой проект Cordova и подключил jQuery Mobile. Когда просто прописываю `document.getElementById('area').innerHTML = "Hello";` в эмуляторе показывает `Hello`, но когда я хочу это сделать в функции что бы при нажатии на кнопку высвечивалось это сообщение то ничего не происходит.

```
function show() {
    document.getElementById('area').innerHTML = "Hello";
}
<input type="button" value="Показать" onclick="show()" />
```

Работаю в Visual Studio 2015 и эмулирую через Ripple - Nexus (Galaxy). В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Как насчет показать, как вы *делаете через функцию*?

Comment: Проблема где-то в вашем коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему таким способом:

```
document.getElementById('show-area').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('area').innerHTML = "Hello";
})
<input type="button" value="Показать" id="show-area" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Почему же не работает? Все прекрасно работает

https://jsfiddle.net/zzaopw77/

```
<div id="area"></div>
<input type="button" value="Показать" onclick="show()" />

function show() {
    document.getElementById('area').innerHTML = "Hello";
}
```